# Is the Soloy Dual Pac recognised as two engines or one engine?

Tags: faa-regulations, piston-engine, pilot-certification, aircraft-certification

The [Soloy Dual Pac](http://www.soloy.com/Products/Fixed%20Wing%20Aircraft/Soloy%20Dual%20Pac/default.aspx) apparently allows two engines to rotate one propeller -- here's a picture of it on an Otter:

[image]

Is this recognised as a centreline thrust twin engine aircraft, a "standard" twin engine aircraft or just an aircraft with a single engine for FAA certification? What about for pilot licensing?

Comment: I don't know the answer (and I'm not familiar with the Soloy Dual Pac), but isn't this situation similar to a twin-engine single-rotor helicopter, where two engines both drive the same rotor? Those are definitely considered multi-engine. (And the PT6 cores used in the Soloy Dual Pac are also commonly used in helicopters as the PT6B and PT6C variants.)

Comment: @TypeIA: I'd say it's even more similar to the [Allison T40](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allison_T40) - two power sections, _two_ propellers (contra-rotating), but a single common gearbox, which was enough to have it considered a single engine.

Answer (score 7):

According to the [certificate](http://rgl.faa.gov/Regulatory_and_Guidance_Library/rgstc.nsf/0/e12680b66a5e1ef986256fe0006aef6c/%24FILE/SE00482SE.pdf) is a

> Twin Power Section Turboprop

and, later, note 7: (emphasis mine)

> This engine is certificated as a unit comprising two separate power sections with the capability of single engine operation with either power section alone in multi-engine airplanes. **The unit is also approved as a single engine with either or both engines operating continuously**.

No explicit remark is given about pilot licensing, but given the note reported, I would say that a licence for a single engine is sufficient.

Comment: To me the bolded section sounds like it's main purpose is to imply single-engine rating is sufficient to operate it.

Comment: @JanHudec I thought I wrote exactly that, haven't I?

Comment: Would someone with only an AMEL rating also be allowed to fly it? (My understanding is that AMEL without ASEL is rare and expensive but technically possible?)

Answer (score 0):

Two engines with the crankshaft welded, would be classified as a single engine. But when both crankshafts are connected with "one way cluck", a pure bureaucrat would call it multi-engines. A logical person would ask, how different would be to fly an aircraft with the crankshaft welded as a single piece or interconnected with one way clutches?

Both would fly in the same way. We expect that an intelligent person would classify it as a single engine as far as only one control is used for both engines. A helicopter is different because it uses more than one control.

Comment: More than one control for what?